# Filter XPath to get list and leave out multiple properties with same property name

Tags: excel, xpath

Through a XMLImport function in Excel I retrieve a JSON set of data. I would like to retrieve a list of ONLY all the names of the pools (in Example below, only 'Men Singles A' and 'Men Singles B').

Because the array of data has different properties called `/name` I do not know a way to filter out all the `/name`  properties that are part of the `/teams` property.

```
[
  {
    "poolId": 864,
    "position": 0,
    "name": "Men Singles A",
    "totTeams": 7,
    "nrPlayersInTeam": 1,
    "teams": {
      "6453": {
        "id": 6453,
        "name": "Peter",
          {
            "id": 3886,
            "name": "Peter",
          }
        ]
      },
      "6501": {
        "id": 6501,
        "name": "Jack",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 3912,
            "name": "Jack",
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "poolId": 865,
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Men Singles B",
    "totTeams": 22,
    "nrPlayersInTeam": 1,
    "teams": {
      "6406": {
        "id": 6406,
        "name": "John",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 3844,
            "name": "John",
          }
        ]
      },
      "6408": {
        "id": 6408,
        "name": "Matthew",
        "players": [
          {
            "id": 3845,
            "name": "Matthew",
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  }
]
```

When trying the following ImportXML function with a Xpath selection, I get a list of all the `/name/` properties found in the JSON array.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tournia.net/api/v2/test/pools?tournamentUrl=test&_format=xml";"//name")

Retrieved List:

Men Singles A
Peter
Peter
Jack
Jack
Men Singles B
John
John
Mtthew
Matthew
```

What would be the appropriate XPath code to only get a list of all the pool names?

Comment: Would it be helpful to see XML for a question about XPATH instead of JSON, no? But since you have provided a URL maybe `=IMPORTXML("https://www.tournia.net/api/v2/test/pools?tournamentUrl=test&_format=xml";"//item/name")`?

Comment: great, this worked! Didn't realize 'item' worked like this. Wellthat was easy then.Thanks!

Comment: No, not `item` works like this in general. It works in this case because the `XML` is like: `<response><item key="0"><poolId>105</poolId><position>0</position><name>Men Singles A</name>...`. So `item` is an `XML` element. That's why it would have been very helpfully to see the `XML` instead of the `JSON`. `JSON` is absolutelly meaningless for `XPATH`.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks. 
Yes I agree with you getting the XML format would be better but I don't have access behinf the URL